# details.features.has is not a function

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, eslint, ecmascript-2021

I am using angular 13 and es2021(also tried es6 to add 2018)

tsconfig.lib.json

```
...
"lib": ["dom", "es2021"]
...
```

I have following object.

```
export interface UserDetails {
  ...
  features?: Set<UserFeature>;
  ...
}
```

I am trying to check some values as below:

```
this.sessionQuery.details$.subscribe((details: UserDetails) => {
      const enableFF = details.features && (details.features as Set<UserFeature>).has({ feature: 'enableFF ', enabled: true });
 ...
    });
```

there is no issue on IDE but i have following issue at browser:

> core.mjs:6495 ERROR TypeError: details.features.has is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility that the object you receive in your subscription (next) doesn't pass the `features` as a `Set`. You then afterwards tell typescript to consider your `features` as a `Set`, and doing so, you open up your code for such runtime exceptions.

If there is no way to receive an actual `Set` object in your subscription, you will have to instantiate a set containing your data or adjust your logic to not depend on a `Set` method.